# Cypher query: return empty result when adding one match twice

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The query as followings and get empty result. When I remove person-[:TEACH]-lesson, it works fine. Anybody can tell me what is the reason? Cheers

```
start person=node(1)
match person-[:TEACH|LEARN]-lesson,
person-[:TEACH]-lesson
return person,lesson
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a TEACH relation between person and lesson.

```
match person-[:TEACH|LEARN]-lesson,
person-[:TEACH]-lesson
```

is `match person-[:TEACH|LEARN]-lesson` AND `match person[:TEACH]-lesson`, which is a repetition anyway.

```
start person=node(1)
match person-[:TEACH|LEARN]-lesson
return person,lesson
```

will work if you want to match TEACH or LEARN (as long as at least one of them exists, you'll get a result).